# Vertical align multiple text lines

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align an icon with text placed to the left and right of it. I am using Wordpress and bootstrap to create a back/next button navigation for my posts using

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

    <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous col-xs-5">%link</div>', '<span class="fa fa-chevron-left nav-icn-L"></span> <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '%title', 'Previous post link', 'bnNav' ). '</span>'); ?>
    <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-next col-xs-5">%link</div>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '%title', 'Next post link', 'bnNav' ). '</span> <span class="fa fa-chevron-right nav-icn-R"></span>'); ?>

<?php elseif ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) ) : // navigation links for home, archive, and search pages ?>

    <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() ) : ?>
    <div class="nav-previous col-xs-5"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span> Older posts', 'bnNav' ) ); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) : ?>
    <div class="nav-next col-xs-5"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>', 'bnNav' ) ); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

fa fa-arrow creates an arrow icon. I want the text that appears to the right and left of it to stay vertically aligned to the icon as it changes from one line to two. (based on screen size) The title is generated by the post

EDIT

the output generated (for left/back button) is

```
<a rel="next" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=369">
   <span class="fa fa-chevron-left nav-icn-L"></span>
   <span class="meta-nav">Welcome</span>
</a>
```

Comment: can you send url for these issue or add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Could you post an inspector screenshot of the HTML markup that is generated for this?

Comment: made edit for the output of the 'back' button. The 'next' button is similar

Comment: since the problem is only IN css its better to add the snippet of HTML/CSS or link to your site ... like this its hard to see full image

Comment: i would if i could but its on local host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way without tables and flexbox (which requires IE10 and higher).

You can make elements `display: inline-block` and apply `vertical-align: middle` to them.

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/bbvpaLgd/2/

Comment: cross browser is importnat, vertical-align middle never seems to work for me

Comment: This property is a bit tricky. It should be applied to all elements that supposed to be vertically centered and NOT to their container. Also elements have to be inline blocks.

Comment: does it need a defined width to work? just can't seem to get them to align beside each other when there isn't enough space. The text goes underneath icon and then starts wrapping

Comment: No, I set width only for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a parent div or p tag for what you want vertical aligned? Vertical align is something that is more tricky then it should be, but, it is because there are a great deal of unknowns.

Let's say the area you have is 250 pixels in height that you need to have text vertical aligned in.
Here's some CSS to achieve it simply:

```
line-height:250px;
```

Unfortunately that only works for one line, but, I like to cheat a bit on this. I add a margin-top with a negative number to bring it back up just above my text size. So a size 12 font I would subtract twelve from the original line height. So for example:

```
.textplacer { line-height:250px; }
.textplacerTwo { line-height:250px; margin-top:-235px; }

<div class="textplacer">your content</div>
<div class="textplacerTwo">your content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: .25em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 250px;
}
a.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="flex" rel="next" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=369">
  <span class="fa fa-chevron-left nav-icn-L"></span>
  <span class="meta-nav">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</a>
```

OR..you could use CSS tables

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: .25em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 250px;
  display: table;
}
a span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a span.fa {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a rel="next" href="http://localhost/wordpress/?p=369">
  <span class="fa fa-chevron-left nav-icn-L"></span>
  <span class="meta-nav">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</a>
```

Comment: that's what im looking for visually, i cant tell if it works on one line since the box is defined size

Comment: one other comment, can it be made more specific. The way the csswritten it will apply to every a link etc

Comment: Unless you can show us your output in a demo it's hard to help beyond our own guesswork. Certainly, both of those should work in a single "line"

Comment: Yes, the demo here is **deliberately** generic (it's only a demo after all)...you would have to make it more specific in your own code.